# Having issues with ZXing.Mobile for Xamarin c# ANDROID

Tags: c#, android, zxing, xamarin

i'm desperately trying to get ZXing.Mobile working within Xamarin VS2012 C# but I'm struggling to find anything in the net to answer my question! :(

This is the code I have:

```
bnGetComp.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this);

    scanner.Scan().ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            aTbCompName.Text = t.Exception.ToString();
        }
        else if (t.Result != null)
        {
            aTbCompName.Text = t.Result.Text;
        }
    });
};
```

My phone starts the scanner, then scans the barcode, then just empties the text box, I've even tried making it just fill aTbCompName.text with a string value i.e. "TEST" and it still empties it! I can't understand what its doing and I can't stick a break point on it as that doesn't seem to do buggar all in Xamarin...

(Phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note N7000 running the official JB 4.1.2)

Can anyone help?

**Update:**

I've been playing around with it and it does work if I rotate the phone afterwards, any idea why rotating after the barcode has been scanned would then finish the process off and put the result into a text box?

Comment: Something to do with the ViewState being reloaded? How do I call the Viewstate to re-load with the new data? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not work but I have my code running the updates to the UI on the UI thread... See code below...

```
scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
RunOnUiThread(
    () =>
    {
        searchBar.Text = t.Result.Text;
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SearchResultsActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("Description", searchBar.Text);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }));
```